# CS50 Tideman - lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

I have no prior coding experience and i've been on this pset ofr like 3+ days now...very challenging and rewarding, but this last check is driving me crazy.

This is the lock_pairs function i wrote

```
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pair_count ; i++)
    {
        int og_win = pairs[i].winner;
        int temp = pairs[i].loser;

       if (i < 1)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
        else if(creates_cycle(i, og_win, temp) != true)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;

}
```

And this is the function i wrote to check if locking this pair would create a cycle

```
bool creates_cycle(int n, int original_winner, int temp_win_los)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    {
        if (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == true)
        {
            if ( pairs[j].winner == temp_win_los )
            {
                if ( pairs[j].loser == original_winner )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp_win_los = pairs[j].loser;
                    creates_cycle(n, original_winner, temp_win_los);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am pretty satisfied of being able to reach this point in the pset, but i really don't understand why and where my code is faulty.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You have a recursive call to `creates_cycle`, but what happens with the value that it *returns*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude mmmm i guess it is passed to the lock_pair function to determine if somewere the cycle is created or not....but you got me thinking...

Comment: No, the returned value is simply ignored, and the loop continues. If you want to return early from a function, you must have an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean adding a return statement before calling the function again?
i tried but it doesn't work. 
like:
`return creates_cycle(n, original_winner, temp_win_los);`

Comment: Perhaps you should only return if the recursive call in turn returns `true` or `false`? Like for example `if (creates_cycle(n, original_winner, temp_win_los)) { return true; }`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude first, thanks for your help! mmm i tried to change the code in that way, but the error message remains the same.